# Changing window in javaFX app is too slow

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I am developing an application with multiple windows in javafx, to create a new window I am using this method:

```
 public static void LaunchNextSceneWithWait(String fxmlName, String title){

    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(SceneLoader.class.getClassLoader().getResource("scia/cbtav3/view/"+fxmlName));
        Stage stage = new Stage();
        stage.setTitle(title);
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.showAndWait();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But every time a new window is created it does it too slowly and de usage of memory increase significantly, maybe the way I'm doing it is very bad, in the next method the new window is launched every time a button is clicked

```
 @Override
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

    if(event.getSource() == btPrint){

        SceneLoader.LaunchNextSceneWithWait(Constants.PRINT_VIEW, Constants.TITLE_PRINT_WINDOW);

    }else if(event.getSource() == btLoanSTD){

        SceneLoader.LaunchNextSceneWithWait(Constants.LOAN_VIEWSTD, Constants.TITLE_LOAN_WINDOW);

    }else if(event.getSource() == btLoanEMP){

        SceneLoader.LaunchNextSceneWithWait(Constants.LOAN_VIEWEMP, Constants.TITLE_LOAN_WINDOW);

    }else if(event.getSource() == btOut){

        SceneLoader.LaunchNextSceneWithWait(Constants.OUT_VIEW, Constants.TITLE_OUT_WINDOW);

    }else if(event.getSource() == btIn){

        SceneLoader.LaunchNextSceneWithWait(Constants.IN_VIEW, Constants.TITLE_BUY_WINDOW);

    }else if(event.getSource() == btReq){

        SceneLoader.LaunchNextSceneWithWait(Constants.REQUISITION_VIEW, Constants.TITLE_REQUISITION_WINDOW);

    }else if(event.getSource() == btRep){

        SceneLoader.LaunchNextSceneWithWait(Constants.REPORT_VIEW, Constants.TITLE_REPORT_WINDOW);

    }else if(event.getSource() == btManagment){

        SceneLoader.LaunchNextSceneWithWait(Constants.MANAGMENT_VIEW, Constants.TITLE_MANAGMENT_WINDOW);

    }

}
```

I would like to know how the LaunchNextSceneWithWait () method can be rebuild to improve the performance of the app.

Thanks!

Comment: Having two many stages in my opinion is not very good idea + not very user friendly. In any case the problem doesn't lies on the two snippets of code. Either the fxml files are huge or the controllers of those fxml files are doing a lot of work.

Comment: Did you try to measure how long each step takes? The too immediate suspects are `FXMLLoader.load` and `stage.showAndWait`.